# How can I create a python virtual environment that only includes one version of python/pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I had been under the impression that if I created a python environment with a specific python version, it would use just that version, but it seems I was mistaken:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m venv pyenv
$ ls pyenv
$ ls pyenv/bin
activate      activate.fish  easy_install      pip   pip3.8  python3
activate.csh  Activate.ps1   easy_install-3.8  pip3  python
```

Is there any reason why older versions of python need to exist alongside the current one in my venv? And can I specify not to, or should I just manually delete the python2/pip?

Comment: I dont see any Python 2 there. Are you assuming `python` is Python 2?

Comment: Yes, I was, but I see that it is a link. But why are there 3 pips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your virtual environment, all the `python*` executables will point to the same version.  You can see this from the symbolic links:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m venv pyenv

$ cd pyenv/bin

$ ls -l python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 [user] [group]  7 May 28 05:49 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 [user] [group] 16 May 28 05:49 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
```

Similarly all the `pip` executables will be copies of the same file:

```
$ ls -l pip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 [user] [group] 212 May 28 05:49 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 [user] [group] 212 May 28 05:49 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 [user] [group] 212 May 28 05:49 pip3.6

$ diff3 pip*
[no output]
```

This means, for example, that once you have run the `activate` script so that this `bin` directory is in your `PATH`, you will find the `python` in your virtual environment regardless of whether you type `python` or `python3`.

The same is true of python scripts which you invoke with `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for example.

Only if you explicitly invoke a different version of python (for example `python2`) or give a full path to the python executable (for example `/usr/bin/python`) might you find another version located elsewhere on your system.